# Develop a function that takes a list of integers that defines it the longest continuous chain of identical numbers

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Please help.

Develop a function that takes a list of integers that defines it the longest continuous chain of identical numbers. The result of the function must be a pair (number, length of the chain)

my code:-

```
let findMaxSeq (nums: int list) = 
let foldFun (curN, len, (curWinN, curWinLen)) n = 
match len, curWinLen with 
| 0, 0 -> (n, 1, (n,1)) 
| 0, _ -> (n, 1, (curWinN,curWinLen)) 
| _ when n = curN -> 
let newLen = len+1 
if (newLen>curWinLen) then (n, newLen, (n, newLen)) else (n, newLen, (curWinN, curWinLen))
| _ -> (n, 1, (curWinN, curWinLen))

let (_, _, (winner)) = nums |> List.fold foldFun (0, 0, (0, 0))
winner
```

but don't compile - in second let i have error:-

> Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out, this was just an indentation problem - F# is an indentation sensitive language (spaces have meaning) and so you need to indent nested blocks further. Your function works just fine when it is indented correctly!

```
let findMaxSeq (nums: int list) = 
  let foldFun (curN, len, (curWinN, curWinLen)) n = 
    match len, curWinLen with 
    | 0, 0 -> (n, 1, (n,1)) 
    | 0, _ -> (n, 1, (curWinN,curWinLen)) 
    | _ when n = curN -> 
       let newLen = len+1 
       if (newLen>curWinLen) then 
         (n, newLen, (n, newLen)) 
       else 
         (n, newLen, (curWinN, curWinLen))
    | _ -> (n, 1, (curWinN, curWinLen))

  let (_, _, (winner)) = nums |> List.fold foldFun (0, 0, (0, 0))
  winner

findMaxSeq [1;2;2;2;3;3;1;1;1;1;1;4;4]
```

Note that:

- the body of function `foldFun` is indented further than the `let` that defines the function.
- the body of the complex pattern (matching when `n=curN`) is also indented further
- I also split `if` `then` to multiple lines (for readability - this is not required)

Daniel's solution is perfectly fine too - but since you asked about a version based on `List.fold`, I thought I'd answer with a corrected version of your original code.

As an aside, if you wanted to do more operations like this on some actual data (like time series) rather than just solve this for the purpose of learning F#, then [Deedle](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/) which is a library for working with series data has a nice abstraction called `chunkWhile` that splits series into chunks while some condition holds (e.g. while the values are the same) and makes it pretty easy to write this:

```
#r "lib/Deedle.dll"
open Deedle

let findMaxSeq values = 
  let s = Series.ofValues values
  s |> Series.chunkWhile (fun k1 k2 -> s.[k1] = s.[k2])
    |> Series.map(fun k chunk -> s.[k], Series.countKeys chunk)
    |> Series.values
    |> Seq.maxBy snd

findMaxSeq [1;2;2;2;3;3;1;1;1;1;1;4;4]
```

Answer (score 3):

Could indentation be the problem? It compiles when formatted like this:

```
let findMaxSeq (nums: int list) = 
  let foldFun (curN, len, (curWinN, curWinLen)) n = 
    match len, curWinLen with 
    | 0, 0 -> (n, 1, (n,1)) 
    | 0, _ -> (n, 1, (curWinN,curWinLen)) 
    | _ when n = curN -> 
      let newLen = len+1 
      if (newLen>curWinLen) then (n, newLen, (n, newLen)) 
      else (n, newLen, (curWinN, curWinLen))
    | _ -> (n, 1, (curWinN, curWinLen))
  let (_, _, (winner)) = nums |> List.fold foldFun (0, 0, (0, 0))
  winner
```

This looked like a fun challenge, so I took a stab at it.

```
let findMaxRepeatedValue xs = 
  let rec loop (maxVal, maxCount) (curVal, curCount) = function
  | [] -> if curCount > maxCount then (curVal, curCount) else (maxVal, maxCount)
  | x::xs when x = curVal -> loop (maxVal, maxCount) (curVal, curCount + 1) xs
  | x::xs -> 
    if curCount > maxCount then loop (curVal, curCount) (x, 1) xs
    else loop (maxVal, maxCount) (x, 1) xs
  match xs with
  | [] -> invalidArg "xs" "empty list"
  | [x] -> (x, 1)
  | x::xs -> loop (x, 1) (x, 1) xs
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your main question has been answered, here's yet another option/approach, for fun and profit :)

```
let longestChain nums =
    let rec chain lst (num, cnt) = seq {
        match lst with
        | x :: xs -> if x = num then 
                        yield! chain xs (num, cnt+1) 
                     else 
                        yield (num, cnt) 
                        yield! chain xs (x, 1)
        | [] -> yield (num, cnt)
    }
    match nums with
    | x :: xs -> chain xs (x, 1) |> Seq.maxBy snd
    | [] -> failwith "Cannot find the longest chain in an empty list"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt which is generic and uses standard library functions. Since you didn't say what the answer should be when the input sequence is empty, I'm not returning a pair of `number * length` directly, but wrap that up in an option.

```
let inline findMaxSeq xs =
    xs 
    |> Seq.scan (fun state x ->
        match state with
        | Some (y, i) when x = y -> Some (x, i + 1)
        | _ -> Some (x, 1) )
        None
    |> Seq.maxBy (function
        | Some (_, i) -> i 
        | _ -> 0 )

findMaxSeq [1;2;2;2;3;3;1;1;1;1;1;4;4] // Some (1, 5)
findMaxSeq Seq.empty<int>              // None
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, but most F# code I've seen her so far looks to me like C# in disguise. I am sure *functional* F# programmers can do better, along the lines of this Haskell solution:

```
maxrv = maximumBy (comparing fst) . map (\xs -> (length xs, xs)) . group
```

Comment: -1 Very good point but sorry, but can it be a comment please?

Comment: F# doesn't have a `group` function like Haskell's, but once you write one you can produce a solution almost exactly like your own ([see .NET Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/dLoajH)).

Comment: @Daniel it seems that `Series.chunkWhile` is something like it, see answer from @Thomas Petricek.

Comment: Yep. Looks similar. That's from a library he wrote called Deedle.